# Rails model directly use other class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing Rails app and i see that i could refactor my code. Just can't find how. 
I have many models like Company, News, Profile and many more which use Image upload. So in every class i must always copy-paste 30 rows of methods which implement always the same logic - upload_image, get_image_name, delete_image. 
 How is possible to do, that my Model class would automatically have the methods from somewhere else? I would like to just put to the Model - load 'GlobalMethods', or even somehow include the methds in activerecord:base to just have them for every class and i would use whenever i want. 
And from controller i would just leave as it is. For example - News.upload_image and it would do this same as this logic would be in original model. 
Please explain with example, because i have readed more and didn't understand or it even possible.

At this moment i did:

```
#models/concerns/uploading.rb
module Uploading
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def do_upload
        puts 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
    end
  end
end
```

and model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Uploading
end
```

and i get this error:

> uninitialized constant Company::Uploading

My rails version: '4.2.5' 
I did server restarts after every try 
My application.rb file looks:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Vca
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.autoload_paths += %W(
      #{config.root}/app/models/concerns/uploading.rb
    )
  end
end
```

Still the same

> NameError in CompaniesController#index
>
> uninitialized constant Company::Uploading

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Uploading  # <-- error
end
```

I have gem 'Spring'. I turned off server, in terminal i runned "spring stop" and started server. But it didn't solve this.

Comment: `concerns` are enabled by default since Rails 4. If you are still on Rails 3 you should load the path with concerns, take a look please on this gist example https://gist.github.com/dhh/1014971

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

For example

**app/models/concerns/my_concern.rb**

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # common stuff here
  end

  class_methods do
    # define class methods here
  end
end
```

**app/models/my_model.rb**

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyConcern

  # ...
end
```

By the way, you can refer to the model class with `self` in the `included` block and out of any instance methods, and inside the methods within the `class_methods` block.

Comment: gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

Comment: Have you modified `autoload_paths`? What if `include ::Uploading`?

Comment: No. i did nothing more than in example.

Comment: Please paste the full path (starts from rails root) of the file `uploading.rb`.

Comment: module Sta
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.autoload_paths += %W(
      #{config.root}/app/models/concerns/uploading.rb
    )
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that your standard rails project includes a folder called `concerns` under your `models` folder.

Create a module in that folder, `image_handling.rb`

```
module ImageHandling
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    # ...(include all your common methods here)
  end
end
```

In your Company, News, Profile models call the concern...

```
class Company < ActiveReecord::Base
  include ImageHandling
  ...
end
```

Comment: did you stop and restart your server?

Comment: You're not using the `spring` gem, are you?  If so, you should do `spring stop` after stopping server and before restarting server.

Comment: Yes, i see this gem is listed. It was on fresh created rails project.

Comment: Is there any other way than this? I can't make it work.

Comment: Did you make any progress?  You're running development server, right? `rails s` ? And you said that before you run `rails s` you ran `spring stop` ?

Comment: Yes to everything. No progress.. I had to make it the hard way and do much repeatable code. Used much time and didn't solve it. But anyway I want to clear this out, because i plan to use this many times for more Dry and clean code.